# Отправка html формы без input

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Подскажите, я могу передать данные из html формы, если они хранятся не в input, а, например, в `<div>` или `<td>` просто присвоив ем атрибут `name`, как это делается с  `<input>`? Интересует не сборка массива вручную при помощи js, а отправка сразу на обработчик через атрибут action тега `form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не можете. Но можете отправить данные из `<input type="hidden" ...`, что Вам, скорее всего, и нужно.

Comment: Также можно передавать данные в атрибутах `name="dataName"` и `value="dataValue"` в тегах `<button>`. Соответственно, форма может содержать одни лишь `<button>` без единого `<input>`. Отправятся на сервер лишь те данные, которые были указаны в той кнопке, которую нажали для `submit`. Данные из других кнопок не отправятся на сервер.